# How to consume API from AWS API Gateway integrated with Lambda function in Java?

Tags: java, reactjs, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to consume API in React app but I'm getting this error in response.

```
{errorMessage: "An error occurred during JSON parsing", errorType: "java.lang.RuntimeException", stackTrace: Array(0), cause: {…}}
cause:
cause: {errorMessage: "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String o…MemoryAsInputStream@727803de; line: 1, column: 1]", errorType: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException", stackTrace: Array(6)}
errorMessage: "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@727803de; line: 1, column: 1]"
errorType: "java.io.UncheckedIOException"
```

Here's the POST request made from React.

```
    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = "{\"type\":\"select\",\"startdate\":\""+this.state.startdate+"\",\"enddate\":\""+this.state.enddate+"\"}";
        const url = "<API Gateway endpoint>";
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: "{\"type\":\"select\",\"startdate\":\"2020-12-15 09:59:59\",\"enddate\":\"2021-01-13 21:37:43\"}"
        });
        const body = await response.json();
        this.setState({invoices : body, isLoading:false})
        console.log(this.state.invoices);
    }
```

Most probably the issue is with the Java handler method not able to parse request data. I'm not sure how to structure the request body such that Lambda handler accepts the request body as input parameter.

```
    public static String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
        Connection conn = createConnection();
        Statement stmt = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        <JDBC stuff>
        return jsonObject.toString();
    }
```

Comment: are you using LAMBDA or LAMBDA_PROXY integration with Api Gateway?

Comment: I'm using LAMBDA integration

Answer (score 0):

For API Gateway I think the Java handler class need to implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>.
Then you should be able to get json string from event.getBody(), you can either deserialize the json string or directly parse it. For response you need to construct APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent object.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it using Map<String, String> as input parameter's type.
The JSON in response's body got translated to key-value pairs.